# XSLT: Remove leading whitespace on multiple lines, keeping newlines

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to transform

```
<description>
    aaa bbb ccc
    ddd eee fff gggggg
    hhh
    iii jjjj
</description>
```

to

```
<description>
aaa bbb ccc
ddd eee fff gggggg
hhh
iii jjjj
</description>
```

Hence I want to remove, for every line, the leading spaces.
Can this be done using XSLT? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is regular expression replacement support in XSLT/XPath 2 and later where you can use `replace(., '^[ \t]+', '', 'm')` to remove leading blanks and tabs from each line:

```
<xsl:template match="description">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^[ \t]+', '', 'm')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks!  The 'm' (multi-line-flag) is key here I guess.